# How to read in multiple list of dictionaries outputed from API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a application that is returning multiple list of dictionaries in this exact format:

```
 [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}][{'key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}]
```

How can I read in the entire lists of dictionaries as is and separate the lists for further analysis in future code?

I tried reading in the data like so into one variable:

```
  a = [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}][{'key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}]
```

but got error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Comment: Can you share what code you have tried!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I tried assigning it to a variable, see where I have assigned `a`. Thats all I know

Comment: Seems like a bug in the API... that surely is meant to be: `[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}]` - is that definitely not the case?

Comment: @JonClements that is definitely not the case.

Comment: is the list supposed to be `[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}],[{'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}]`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh that is incorrect

Comment: @Rusty Is the API supposed to be returning JSON data or just literally text? Could you give a bit more context?

Comment: @JonClements I am not aware of the nuances of the application I am working with since it is third party, so the data I was given is the only format I have and cant comment on anything outside that.

Comment: Okay... so are you interacting with the API (maybe using the `requests` library or the builtin `urllib`) or are you saying someone's given you this data in a file or something?

Comment: @JonClements this data was given to me in a file. Should I iterate over the file?

Comment: Can you show the first N lines of your file in a codeblock? At the moment it sounds like you're copying/pasting from the file into Python code which you almost definitely don't want to be doing. Or, someone borked the data when writing it the file.

Comment: @JonClements thank you for the help, however since this is a POC Devesh answer will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crude way of handling the string you made is by doing `string.split` and `string.replace` is as follows.

```
import ast

a = "[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}][{'key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}]"
li = []
#split of ']['
for elem in a.split(']['):
    #Replace elements in dictionary to make the string json compliant
    d = elem.strip('[]')
    #Use literal_eval to convert to dictionary
    dct = ast.literal_eval(d)
    #Append parsed dictionary to a list
    li.append(dct)

print(li)
#[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}]
```

Comment: Great, Glad to be of help!

Comment: @RustyShackleford just be aware that if you have genuine `[`, `]` or `'`s in your keys or values this'll blow up quite nicely :p (or even worse - silently corrupt your data)

Comment: Great point! Wonder how can I take care of those, or even if I can take care of those given the data format is not very clear

Comment: @Devesh could make it slightly more robust by doing `d = elem.strip('[]')` so only leading/trailing ones are removed instead of anywhere in the text and then use `ast.literal_eval` on that instead of `json.loads` to avoid the possibility of unintentionally removing any valid `"`s... That still leaves the possibility of `][` being  valid characters and then causing things to break on the split but... would add a little robustness

Comment: I have updated my code according to your suggestion @JonClements

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this. The benefit using the below suggested approach is:

- No matter, how many dictionaries are there in the string, it will work `[{...}][{...}][{...}]`.
- No matter, how many spaces are there between `]` and `[`, it will work `[{...}]     [{...}]     [{...}]   [{...}]`.

Thanks to regular expressions.

So, just have a look at below one where I have tried to simplify/solve your problem.

```
>>> import re
>>> import json
>>> 
>>> a = "[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}][{'key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}]"
>>> 
>>> # Create a list of dictionaries from the exisitng string (valid for many dicts)
... # If there will be spaces b/w ] & [ or before/after [ & ], it will work
... 
>>> a = re.sub(r"\s*\]\s*\[\s*", ", ", a)
>>> a
"[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}, {'key3':'value3','key4':'value4'}]"
>>>
```

> **Note:** JSON uses `"` to surround keys and values (strings). So, converting the above string with `'` will throw Exception, if we will try to convert it into list of dictionaries.

```
>>> a = json.loads(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
>>>
```

> **Let's fix it** by first replacing all `'` with `"` and after that using `json.loads()` to get the actual object from its string representation.

```
>>> a = a.replace("'", '"')
>>> a
'[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}, {"key3":"value3","key4":"value4"}]'
>>> 
>>> a = json.loads(a)
>>> a
[{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}, {'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}]
>>>
```

> **Inspecting** the list created above.

```
>>> a[0]
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> 
>>> a[1]
{'key3': 'value3', 'key4': 'value4'}
>>> 
>>> a[1]["key3"]
'value3'
>>>
>>> a[1]["key4"]
'value4'
>>>
```